# A question related to inequality in Selberg Sieve

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Consider these images related to Theory of selberg Sieve , taken from notes on Sieve theory Of Prof. Rudnick. [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html)

Note: Earlier it was asked on Mathoverflow but due to no response I am asking here and will delete from there.
Image 1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWngZ.png)

Image 2 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeM8a.png)

In last Line of 2nd Image I am unable to deduce how author wrote $z^2$ ie how from (4) $O(\sum_{d_1 ,d_2}|\lambda_{d_1} | |\lambda_{d_2}|)$ is proved to be $\leq  z^2$.

It is given that d$\leq z$ and $\lambda_d =0$ for d>z but I am unable to find a relation between $\lambda_d$ and z.

Can you please help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By manipulating the main term with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it is possible to show that $|\lambda_d|\le1$ (Have a look at Nathanson's GTM164 *Additive Number Theory*). Thus the latter sum will be $\le z^2$. Hope this addresses your concern!